# Istio installation failed with windows node as worker

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I have created a kubernetes cluster with CentOS7 as master node and a windows as worker. I am not able to install istio using master.
✔ Istio core installed
✘ Istiod encountered an error: failed to wait for resource: resources not ready after 5m0s: timed out waiting for the condition

Is it possible to install istio if there is a windows node as worker?

Comment: No, see: github.com/istio/istio/issues/39788#issuecomment-1226352856 and github.com/istio/istio/issues/27893